# change type with python

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
x = "[(7, 'N°001C/MITP/CAB/UGP-BAD/2023 Du 30/01/2024', 'Recrutement d’une ONG/Firme pour les services d’accompagnement social,\r communication, sensibilisation des populations de la zone du projet d’Aménagement et de bitumage de la route\r Lola- Frontière de la Cote d’Ivoire', 'Sensibilisation', 'Guinée', 'Qualité et Coût', '', datetime.date(2024, 2, 22), None, datetime.date(2024, 2, 5), 2), (9, 'N°001/MPFPV/PERSIF/UCP/2024', 'Mission d’audit des comptes du PERSIF. Exercices 2023 et 2024\r(l’audit de clôture inclus)', '', 'Guinée', 'Qualité et Coût', '', datetime.date(2024, 2, 9), None, datetime.date(2024, 2, 5), 2)]"
```

This is the response that a server sends me when a client sends a request. How can I convert this string of characters into usable data, i.e. :

```
x = [(7, 'N°001C/MITP/CAB/UGP-BAD/2023 Du 30/01/2024', 'Recrutement d’une ONG/Firme pour les services d’accompagnement social,\r communication, sensibilisation des populations de la zone du projet d’Aménagement et de bitumage de la route\r Lola- Frontière de la Cote d’Ivoire', 'Sensibilisation', 'Guinée', 'Qualité et Coût', '', datetime.date(2024, 2, 22), None, datetime.date(2024, 2, 5), 2), (9, 'N°001/MPFPV/PERSIF/UCP/2024', 'Mission d’audit des comptes du PERSIF. Exercices 2023 et 2024\r(l’audit de clôture inclus)', '', 'Guinée', 'Qualité et Coût', '', datetime.date(2024, 2, 9), None, datetime.date(2024, 2, 5), 2)]
```

a list of tuples.

`x = ast.literal_eval(x)` doesn't work here, because that doesn't support parsing `datetime.date` objects.

Comment: the first variable is a string, hence the square brackets at the beginning and end. how do you turn this variable into a list?

Comment: Have the server send you proper json then decode it with the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module, don't try to parse what you currently have with `eval` or someone will hack your server, you can inject any code in `eval`, even an entire crypto mining app.

Comment: An easy solution would be to `eval()` the string, but you want to be very, very careful with that. Only if you can be sure you trust the server, and the connection is secure is this something you could consider. And even then, it might be better to do some more targeted parsing, if you know what the structure of the response is supposed to  be.

Comment: @AhmedAEK  OK, but in my data there's a datetime type, but this type doesn't work with JSON. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Grismar with eval(), I get errors because of \r

Comment: Use any [string format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat) to convert datetime to strings and back, alternatively use regular expressions with `re` to find the string quotes `'`

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, because here we need to parse `datetime.date` objects, which `ast.literal_eval` cannot do'

Comment: I removed all the stuff from the question that was distracting from what the actual question was. @pts I updated your answer, please check if I made no mistake.

Comment: The obvious solution to the underlying problem would be to have the server send the date as a string in a standard format like `"2024-02-05"`.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Please revert your changes to the question and to my answer. The OP needs a solution which can parse lists and tuples recursively. Your edits discard this and oversimplify the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`, but that's unsafe if the attacker controls the string x: the attacker then can run any code of their choice on your computer. Using `ast.literal_eval` is safe, but it doesn't support `datetime`.

Here is a dirty hack which converts `datetime.date` constructors to strings:

```
import ast
import datetime
import re

x = r"[(7, 'N°001C/MITP/CAB/UGP-BAD/2023 Du 30/01/2024', 'Recrutement d’une ONG/Firme pour les services d’accompagnement social,\r communication, sensibilisation des populations de la zone du projet d’Aménagement et de bitumage de la route\r Lola- Frontière de la Cote d’Ivoire', 'Sensibilisation', 'Guinée', 'Qualité et Coût', '', datetime.date(2024, 2, 22), None, datetime.date(2024, 2, 5), 2), (9, 'N°001/MPFPV/PERSIF/UCP/2024', 'Mission d’audit des comptes du PERSIF. Exercices 2023 et 2024\r(l’audit de clôture inclus)', '', 'Guinée', 'Qualité et Coût', '', datetime.date(2024, 2, 9), None, datetime.date(2024, 2, 5), 2)]"
if 0:
  x = eval(x, {'datetime': datetime})  # Unsafe.
else:
  x = re.sub(r'\b(datetime[.]date\([\d, ]+\))', r"'\1'", x)  # Safe.
  x = ast.literal_eval(x)  # Safe.
print(x)
```

A proper parser for `datetime.date` is doable but more complex. You can start with the *tokenize* module:

```
import tokenize
x = r"[(7, 'N°001C/MITP/CAB/UGP-BAD/2023 Du 30/01/2024', 'Recrutement d’une ONG/Firme pour les services d’accompagnement social,\r communication, sensibilisation des populations de la zone du projet d’Aménagement et de bitumage de la route\r Lola- Frontière de la Cote d’Ivoire', 'Sensibilisation', 'Guinée', 'Qualité et Coût', '', datetime.date(2024, 2, 22), None, datetime.date(2024, 2, 5), 2), (9, 'N°001/MPFPV/PERSIF/UCP/2024', 'Mission d’audit des comptes du PERSIF. Exercices 2023 et 2024\r(l’audit de clôture inclus)', '', 'Guinée', 'Qualité et Coût', '', datetime.date(2024, 2, 9), None, datetime.date(2024, 2, 5), 2)]"
print(list(tokenize.tokenize(iter((x.encode('utf-8'), b'')).__next__)))  # Safe.
```

Then iterate over the tokens and build str, int, None, `datetime.date`, `list` and `tuple` literals.

Answer (score 1):

A more refined solution than the `tokenize` module suggested by @pts is `ast` and pattern matching.

The AST of the expression in question can be generated as easy as:

```py
import ast

tree = ast.parse('datetime.date(2024, 2, 5)')
print(ast.dump(tree, indent = 2))
```

```py
Module(
  body=[
    Expr(
      value=Call(
        func=Attribute(
          value=Name(id='datetime', ctx=Load()),
          attr='date',
          ctx=Load()),
        args=[
          Constant(value=2024),
          Constant(value=2),
          Constant(value=5)],
        keywords=[]))],
  type_ignores=[])
```

Writing the `case` statement for that is basically just copy and paste:

```py
match tree:                                      # Checks if tree is
  case ast.Module(                               # a Module
    body = [                                     # whose .body is a list of
      ast.Expr(                                  # exactly one Expr,
        value = ast.Call(                        # whose .value is a Call
          func = ast.Attribute(                  # etc.
            value = ast.Name(id = 'datetime'),
            attr = 'date'
          ),
          args = [
            ast.Constant(),                      # This is typically fine
            ast.Constant(value = int()),         # but you can also do this
            ast.Constant(value = 5)              # if you want to be even stricter.
          ]
        )
      )
    ]
  ):
    args = tree.body[0].value.args
    print(date(*[arg.value for arg in args]))    # 2024-02-05

  case _:
    print('Malformed date')
```